# Как выводить ImageView по очереди?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать такое маленькое приложение, которое будет показывать картинки по очереди. Есть две кнопки вперед и назад,для показа следующей и предыдущей картинки. Теперь что я сделал-> Я создал класс Who,который имеет поля name(String) и photo(ImageView). Также сделал конструктор, `Who(String name,ImageView photo){this.name=name;
this.photo = photo};`

Далее в классе главной активности я создал пару переменных типа ImageView. Для каждой применил метод setImageResourse. Далее создал столько же переменных типа 'Who' и отправил туда name и переменную типа ImageView. Потом все эти переменные вида Who я сохранил в ArrayList типа Who. Далее создав метод`showCurrentPerson()` я присваиваю моему `image` текущую картинку. Но программа не запустилась и вывела ошибку. Где я ошибся? Может нельзя присваивать  переменные ImageView? Ниже привожу MainActivity:

```
public ArrayList<Who> list;

public Button RightButton, WrongButton;

public ImageView ImageOf;
int counter = 0;

int point = 0 ;
TextView name;

private ImageView i1, i2, i3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.righButton);
    WrongButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wrongButton);

    ImageOf = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.leo);
    i2.setImageResource(R.drawable.en);

    Who w1 = new Who("leo",i1);
    Who w2 = new Who("en",i2);

    list.add(w1);
    list.add(w2);

    showCurrentPerson();
}

public void showCurrentPerson() {
    Who cur = new Who();
    cur = list.get(counter);
    ImageOf = cur.photo;
    name.setText(cur.name);
}


public void Wrong(View view) {
    if(counter==list.size())
        counter = 0 ;
    else
        counter++;
}

public void Right(View view) {
    point++;
    if(counter==list.size())
        counter = 0 ;
    else
        counter++;
}
```

Comment: Покажите стек-трейс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в этом месте:

```
i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.leo);
i2.setImageResource(R.drawable.en);
```

Вы пытаетесь манипулировать неинициализированными переменными.

---

Ну и вообще, у Вас весьма странная архитектура.

Правильнее будет в Вашем классе `Who` хранить не `ImageView`, а идентификатор ресурса (в данном случае, изображения).

Comment: Как хранить идентификатор ресурса? Какой тип данных? Who(String name, ? photo) Что должно быть вместо '?' ? ;

Comment: Идентификатор ресурса имеет тип `int`.

Comment: Если правите вопрос "форматирование кода" то постарайтесь не только удалить лишние пробелы, а так же обвернуть весь код в `{}`

Comment: @Naumov, Тут наоборот необходимо убрать последнюю закрывающую скобку, ибо имя метода не указано. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: @post_zeew просто тут не одназначно понятно что опечатка это или ошибка, по этому не стоит вносить такие правки